# An error outside JVM thrown when running the application

Tags: java, jvm-crash, worldwind

I am working on my app based on World Wind Java SDK in Eclipse. Like two weeks ago, I have started to get such error thrown every time I am trying to run the app:

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
> EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x1a97d42a, pid=4136,
>   tid=4888
>       JRE version: 6.0_31-b05   Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.6-b01 mixed mode windows-x86 )   Problematic frame:   C 
>   [ig4icd32.dll+0x3d42a]
>
> An error report file with more information is saved as:
>   C:\thesis\100GreatP\eclipse_ws\test\hs_err_pid4136.log
>
> If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
>   [url]http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp[/url]   The crash
>   happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.   See
>   problematic frame for where to report the bug.

The funny thing is that this happens only if I am trying to display my newly made layer right when the app starts:

```
wwd.getModel().getLayers().add(GreatPlacesIcons);
wwd.addSelectListener(GreatPlacesIcons);
layers = new LayerViewDockable(wwd,"layers");
```

Once I make a comment on those lines of code above, the app will start correctly. Does anyone have an idea of what is going on here?

Comment: It appears that there is some native exception occurring the the API used in these 3 lines of code and it is not handled properly by API (like some null value in native code or invalid pointer etc). If you have access to all the code (native code) of API you can debug it or file a bug on the API

Comment: Are you making a Swing app or an Eclipse RCP app?

Comment: @TimBender - It is a Swing App.

Comment: One more interesting thing - I have tried to uninstall latest update of Java 7 and reboot the system, after that, it worked, but just like for 3 attempts. Then, again, it started to throw such an error.

Comment: it might help to look at that log file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO finally I have solved my problem. The problem was outside code and Eclipse, the problem was in defining one of the JVM Environment variables, CLASSPATH. I have figured it out from the log file, here is its extraction:

> VM Arguments: jvm_args: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252  java_command:
>   org.cnstar.wiki.app.GreatPlaces Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD
>
> Environment Variables: JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre6
>   CLASSPATH=.;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib;
>     PATH=C:/Program
>   Files/Java/jre6/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin;C:/Program
>   Files/Java/jre6/lib/i386;

The variable classpath was pointing to jre7, however, it was not like that anymore since I unistalled Java 7 a few days ago. And when I was running my application, it automatically failed. So I went to (Windows XP) Start -> Control Panels -> System -> Advanced -> Environment variables and changed the variable CLASSPATH so that it was pointing to jre6.